# How can I enqueue a CSS file on a specific Wordpress block template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Situation: I am developing a theme using Wordpress' new [Block Theme paradigm](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/). I would like to enqueue `foo.css` for any pages that are using my `templates/foo.html` template.

What I have tried: I have this function for debugging.

```
function foo_enqueue() {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(
        get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID())
    );
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_enqueue' );
```

The normal Wordpress way of using the `get_page_template_slug` function does not work with Block Theme templates. `get_page_template_slug` only works with traditional PHP based page templates.

I have that debugging function set up to see what page template it would return. It returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conditionally enqueue a stylesheet only for `templates/foo.html` in a block-based theme, check the name of the currently applied template with [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), using the key `_wp_page_template`, eg:

**functions.php**

```
// Register "foo" CSS to use when needed later
function register_foo_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'foo-template-css', get_template_directory_uri(). '/foo.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_foo_style' );

// Enqueue "foo" CSS only if the current post/page uses "foo" template
function foo_enqueue() {
    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true ) == "foo" ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-template-css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_enqueue' );
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/#more-information